# How to add string in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

Hello my code is as follows:

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 0;
WHILE @cnt < 256
BEGIN
SELECT
ITEM1 ,
ITEM2 ,
ITEM3
FROM Table_Name
SET @cnt = @cnt + 3
End
```

I want to do like below:

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 0;
WHILE @cnt < 256
BEGIN
SELECT
ITEM@cnt+1 ,
ITEM@cnt+2 ,
ITEM@cnt+3
FROM Table_Name
SET @cnt = @cnt + 3
End
```

So that it will be executed in a single loop.
Please help me regarding this.

Thank you in advance

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish here? Why loop this?

Comment: what's the expected results supposed to look like

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compose your query using variables, you must use dynamic TSQL to construct your select, then you can execute it with `EXEC(...)`:

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(max)= ' SELECT '
DECLARE @cnt INT = 0;

WHILE @cnt < 256
    BEGIN
        set @cnt = @cnt + 1
        set @sql = @sql + ' ITEM' + cast(@cnt as varchar(max)) + ',' 
    End
set @sql = replace (@sql + ' from #table_name',', from',' from')

exec (@sql)
```